# Multiple Dimensions on one field in Fact Table

Tags: ssas, cube, dimension, analysisservices

I have a fact table containing lines of different types. Based upon each type I have a different dimension table that I need to connect. Is there a solution to this problem without creating different fact tables for each type of line?

When connecting the fact to one dimension, I get the error that one key cannot be found in the dimension table. That's right, because that value exists in another dimension table

Here a picture of what I intend to achieve:

[image: Tables]

Comment: Just *don't* do that. One field should contain *one* type of information. This is no longer a fact table, it's an Entity-Attribute-Value table with all of the disadvantages. It's no longer possible to easily create analytic reports and aggregates from this. In fact, even the Amount and Quantity tables are now useless as you can't sum together resource, item and account amounts or quantities - 5 bananas and $100 don't make 105 of anything

Comment: So what would you suggest? Divide that table into multiple tables per Type?
The fact table structure is directly based on the information I get from our system. Update: "5 bananas and $100 don't make 105" Thats not the case. Quantity is still quantity and Amount is still a monetary value

Comment: A fact table is supposed to reflect a *single* business process. In that fact table each field represents one measure only. Dimensions have their own fields. That's what makes them easy to use.

Comment: `Thats not the case.` it's very much the case. GL account amounts are completely different from resource amounts. You can't sum accounting and resource data. You can compare them to see whether there are accounting errors. Summing them together though may well mean that you are using the same amounts twice - the accounting data probably contains the amounts paid to acquire those resources

Comment: But still I can create an invoice with one item line and one ressource line and one G/L Account line. That's absolutely possible. So what if I want to know the whole amount of this invoice? Then I need all possible lines and sum them by amount. As I understand the only solution would be to create one table per type and connect them via header

Comment: That's actually a *problem*. The rows no longer represent individual events/facts. This is no longer a fact table. In order to rehydrate an event you have to use multiple rows. That's an EAV table. Yes, it's possible. No it's not efficient or easy any more - indexes become meaningless, you'd need to PIVOT to recreate individual measures

Comment: BTW that's why SSAS complains. You're trying to do the exact opposite of what's expected. You'd get similar errors in an OLTP database if you tried to create FK constraints between those tables. Even if you could force SSAS to do what you want (you can't) you'd lose *any* benefit because those measures can't be added any more so SSAS can't precalculate aggregates. Its columnar storage won't be able to put values in the same buckets any more. Querying would probably be slower than using a plain old database table

Comment: Wikipedia's article on [Star Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) offers a simple explanation: `Fact tables record measurements or metrics for a specific event.`. Ralph Kimball's books and articles are some of the best resources into data warehouses and star schemas.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Dynamics NAV (out ERP-System) doesn't use FKs because relationships are handelt by the system not via Database. But thanks for the input. I will split our lines into different parts based on their type and build the cube based upon the new logic